# General file structure and difference between /bin and /dist directory

Tags: java, javascript, actionscript, development-environment

This question is not related to a specific programming language but this is confusing me all the time when it comes to the question how to structure my project directories in a “professional way”.

AFAIK the `bin` directory contains compiled and compressed executable binary files while the `src` directory contains the raw source code and the `build` directory contains uncompressed executables (e.g. for local execution).

According to [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7450051/890144) the `dist` directory contains the compressed/archived output stuff. But what’s the difference between `bin` and `dist` then? And what does a `deploy` folder contain aside from all these folders?

And finally: Where to put the assets (images, JSON, whatever) in? `assets` or `vendor`?

Comment: I think the final question maybe split into a new question of its own, as it is a non-trivial subject and may differ according to project needs. For example, some projects only use a few images, or maybe an icon-font library, in that case an asset folder would be acceptable. Other projects may require to serve images and other resources dynamically, like streaming video, in which case is better to set a CDN server to deliver static files.

Comment: related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/23730882/104380

Answer (score 0):

The folder structures will always specific and different each other based on the technology and build tools we are using. As per the java I can suggest

For core java apps the structure will be

Project folder inside that we will have LIB SRC CLASSES folders 
in LIB all the archievs libraries of java
SRC normally Source code .java files
CLASSES cantaines always compiled java classes.
other files normally We use RESOURCES Folder

And for WEB APPLICATIONS
build structures decided by the build tools and servlet specifications
as per the ServletSpecification
PROJECT FOLDER
inside WEB-INF folder
inside WEB-INF classes and lib folders
out side WEB-INF there are all resources and jsp html script files  should be.

If use ANT TOOL there will be configuration xml file. there we can create and use the made 
the above servlet specified file structure.
If use MAVEN it will take care to create above folder structure automatically from maven folder structures.

If we use plugins of maven and ant in the IDES that will take care every thing.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question with java, I assume the projects you mention are java projects. Have a look at [Standard Directory Layout of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), it might be helpfull.